# Magento 2 - Wordpress Integration url issue

Tags: magento2, category, url, third-party-module, wordpress

I am using a magento 2.1.8 site.
I have installed wordpress in a subdirectory of my root directory.
I have integrated the wordpress and magento site by using fishpig wordpress extension. 
All other things are working fine. Now I got all my wordpress post in this url **www.example.com/blog**

The issue is I have assigned few categories to a post, For example,blog,category1,category2,category3 etc.

When I take the post in browser, it shows the url as **www.example.com/blog/blog/posturl/**.

I want the post url as **www.example.com/blog/category2/posturl/**.

How can I do it? When ?I tried the permalinks extension in wordpress,but still the issue  exist.

Answer (score 6):

**Try settings same as following example:**

```
1. Set your WordPress setup folder name "wp".

2. M2 Admin Menu > WordPress > Path = wp

3. Database: magento2_wp > Table: wp_options

option_id = 1
option_name = siteurl
option_value = http://www.example.com/wp //Folder name of your WordPress installation.
autoupload = yes

option_id = 2
option_name = home
option_value = http://www.example.com/blog //Frontend URL
autoupload = yes
```