# Base URL changed and not affecting website

Tags: magento2, exception, base-url

Our website randomly started showing this error whenever you access a link outside of the home page or try to access the admin panel.

```
Exception #0 (FishPig\WordPress\Model\Integration\IntegrationException): Your home URL (https://www.ourURL.com/documents) is invalid as it does not start with the Magento base URL (https://www.ourURL.com/home).
```

The weird thing is that it the base URL should be https://www.ourURL.com/ (without the /home/). When I SSH into the server and run `n98-magerun2 sys:store:config:base-url:list` I can see that the base and base secure URLs are set correctly.

I've tried running the following commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://www.ourURL.com/"
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://www.ourURL.com/"
```

(I even tried setting it to http(s)://www.ourURL.com/home/ and then setting it back)

```
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I'm kinda out of ideas and have a support ticket open with our web hosting provider, but in the mean time any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Set your WordPress setup folder name "wp".

2. M2 Admin Menu > WordPress > Path = wp

3. Database: wordpress_database > Table: wp_options

option_id = 1
option_name = siteurl
option_value = http://www.example.com/wp //Folder name of your WordPress installation.
autoupload = yes

option_id = 2
option_name = home
option_value = http://www.example.com/blog //Frontend URL
autoupload = yes
```

For more click here :

[Magento 2 - Wordpress Integration url issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209726/magento-2-wordpress-integration-url-issue)

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Running `php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://www.ourURL.com/"`changed the value under `web/unsecure/base_url`. The issue was that I needed to change `web/unsecure/base_link_url` to match it.

Ran the following command for both secure and unsecure.

```
bin/magento config:set web/unsecure/base_link_url 'https://www.ourURL.com/'
```